# Log4j2 + Pattern + Custom + additional args

Tags: log4j2

SPEC : log4j2, Jdk1.6, RedHatLinux.

I have successfully built an customized DB-Appender to redirect logging to 
  DB.

I need to *customize pattern* with additional OBJECTS

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}   %larg "/>
```

Reason : I need to insert the custom objects '%larg'  to DB using the
   Customize DB-Appender

Can somebody provide a example for the same.

Thx

Comment: Can you help me understand what you want to do by showing an example of how you want to provide the input information (through the logger or through the ThreadContext, and on the other hand what you want the output to look like?

Comment: I have to persist large multiple event  objects  stored in a Java BEAN for  information of my applications, they may be in key value pairs within Hashmap   or  timestamp/payload/methods entry/exit.  The persisted info is used for tracking end 2 end  functionality per Webservice Thread requested.

Comment: Also i have customized an Appender to hold a JNDI based Connection pool to persist the Data defined.

Comment: How do you store your application's Java Bean objects in the LogEvent? Do you have a custom LogEvent, or do you store key-value pairs in the context map, or do you have a custom Message implementation?

Comment: Also, how do you want to store the Java Bean fields in the database? Does the table have separate fields like time stamp, payload, method entry/exit? Or does the table have a generic key column and a generic value column?

Comment: Do you have a custom LogEvent  : Yes I need to create the custom LogEvent ... and this is why i need  '%larg'                                                                                                          I have a Java Bean with all of the info as said above, I need to pass the same thu Log4j2 Engine...and With Custom DB Appender with JNDI approach,  I will have to push the Java bean into a Customized PLSQL with equivalent no of Cols for persisting the Java Bean Data.

But I also need to filter out NON persistent logging info to a Flat File as normal case.

Comment: Generally, PatternConverters in PatternLayout know how to extract a piece of data from the LogEvent and write it into a StringBuilder. What does the "%larg" layout pattern converter need to do? Call `toString()` on the Java Bean and write the resulting String into the StringBuilder?

Comment: U are correct, i was able to get <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n </pattern>, but i need to introduce an additional value '%larg' to set identify  and fetch the Java beans  from LogEvent for persistence How should i do this is the problem statement..